# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'release' of undefined

Tags: typescript, redux, rxjs, ngrx, angular5

**Hi guys !**

I need some help.
I would like test my tree of services with a particular structure.

My test looks like :

```
describe(`Service selector`, () => {
  describe(`getCurrentServiceTree`, () => {
    it(`should build the generic service tree`, () => {
      const services = [
        '{http://namespace-example.fr/service/technique/version/1.0}Localpart0',
        '{http://namespace-example.fr/service/technique/version/1.0}Localpart1',
        '{http://namespace-example.fr/service/technique/version/2.0}Localpart2',
        '{http://namespace-example.fr/service/technique/version/3.0}Localpart3',
        '{http://namespace-example.fr/service/technique/version/3.0}Localpart4',
      ];

      const expectedTree: TreeElement<any>[] = [
        {
          name: 'http://namespace-example.fr/service/technique/version/1.0',
          children: [
            {
              name: 'Localpart0',
              children: [],
              isFolded: false,
              cssClass: 'item-localpart',
            },
            {
              name: 'Localpart1',
              children: [],
              isFolded: false,
              cssClass: 'item-localpart',
            },
          ],
          isFolded: false,
          cssClass: 'item-namespace',
        },
        {
          name: 'http://namespace-example.fr/service/technique/version/2.0',
          children: [
            {
              name: 'Localpart2',
              children: [],
              isFolded: false,
              cssClass: 'item-localpart',
            },
          ],
          isFolded: false,
          cssClass: 'item-namespace',
        },
        {
          name: 'http://namespace-example.fr/service/technique/version/3.0',
          children: [
            {
              name: 'Localpart3',
              children: [],
              isFolded: false,
              cssClass: 'item-localpart',
            },
            {
              name: 'Localpart4',
              children: [],
              isFolded: false,
              cssClass: 'item-localpart',
            },
          ],
          isFolded: false,
          cssClass: 'item-namespace',
        },
      ];

      const generatedStore: Partial<IStore> = {
        services: {
          byId: services.reduce(
            (acc, name, index) => ({ ...acc, [`service${index}`]: { name } }),
            {}
          ),
          allIds: services.map((_, index) => `service${index}`),
          isFetchingServices: false,
          selectedServiceId: '',
        },
      };

      expect(getCurrentServiceTree(generatedStore as any)).toEqual(
        expectedTree
      );
    });
  });
});
```

I don't know if it's a TypeScript issue or if is related to RxJS.. or just my code :(

When I put my mouse to getCurrentServiceTree, I have that :

> (alias) getCurrentServiceTree(state: IStore): TreeElement[]
>   import getCurrentServiceTree

I don't know if I use correctly `Partial<T>`.
I can't type generatedStore as  ..
When I put my mouse to , I have that :

> [ts] L'argument de type '() => any' n'est pas attribuable au
>   paramètre de type 'IStore'.   La propriété 'ui' est manquante dans le
>   type '() => any'.

```
export const getCurrentServiceTree = createSelector(
  getSelectedWorkspaceId,
  getServicesAllIds,
  getServicesById,
  (selectedWorkspaceId, servicesAllIds, servicesByIds): TreeElement<any>[] => {
    const baseUrl = `/workspaces/${selectedWorkspaceId}/services`;

    const servicesWithNspLocalpart = servicesAllIds.map(id => ({
      ...findNamespaceLocalpart(servicesByIds[id].name),
      id,
    }));

    const groupedByNamespace = groupByNamespace(servicesWithNspLocalpart);

    return groupedByNamespace.map(nspWithLocalparts => ({
      name: nspWithLocalparts.namespace,
      isFolded: false,
      cssClass: `item-namespace`,
      link: ``,
      children: nspWithLocalparts.localparts.map(localpart => ({
        name: localpart.name,
        isFolded: false,
        cssClass: `item-localpart`,
        link: `${baseUrl}/${localpart.id}`,
        children: [],
      })),
    }));
  }
);
```

What I'm suppose to do ?
Can someone explain me how can I resolve my problem please ?

Comment: Maybe try replacing `const expectedTree: TreeElement<any>[]` with `const expectedTree: any`

Comment: @RichardMatsen Doesn't work because I have children elements :(

Comment: Would help if you could translate the error.

Comment: The argument of type `() => any' can't be assigned to parameter of type 'IStore'. The property 'ui' is missing? from the type '() => any'. (Seen that enough times in English).

Comment: @christophechevalier - mais oui, how about 'any[]'?

Comment: Actually, first of all I would drop types from the test. After all, your expect is doing an equal match - if it succeeds, types are not so relevant. (i.e. duck-typing).

Comment: @LazarLjubenović The error that is returned to me is in the title of my question:
`Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'release' of undefined`

I created a unit test for my service tree.
In my **service selector** I used a `createSelector ()` to get my tree with my service list.
At first, I split the services into 2. A service is composed of a _namespace_ and a _localpart_ in its name.
Then I group by namespace to have a visual adapted.
And finally I return my tree built.
I hope this explanation is good and understandable to you.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović To return to my test **should build the generic service tree**, so I created a `const generatedStore` of type `Partial<IStore>` .
Only, in my expect, I can not attribute to the parameter type `IStore`. And when I put the type "any" to simplify, so I have the error in my console that blocks the launch of my test.

Comment: 'release' must be referenced in your `getCurrentServiceTree` method, as it's not in your test. Please show this method also.

Comment: @RichardMatsen I updated. Normally you can see **getCurrentServiceTree**.  
I do not use release, so I do not see at all what it is.

Comment: Thanks. This is ngrx 'createSelector', no?

Comment: Yes, actually, I use the ngrx library (version 4.1.1) why?

Comment: I'm looking for 'release' in the source, [line 198](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/selector.ts)

Comment: One of the first 3 params doesn't seem to be a properly formed selector.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't pin it down. Maybe it's the way `getCurrentServiceTree` is built with TestBed, perhaps a missing dependency?

Comment: My selector works fine, This is my unitary test that I can not solve.
I check my dependencies but I use **Visual Studio Code** with _tslint_, and everything is ok. My problem lies with the type of the state passed as a parameter of `getCurrentServiceTree()`. For me, I think this is `Partial<IStore>` problem.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović @RichardMatsen I continue to debug ...
When running my tests, I have click on debug and it has open it my browser then I have put pause execution, and finally I can see all the code in vendor.bundle.js:1278.
So, here is a line error for me : 
`var /** @type {?} */ memoizedSelectors = selectors.filter(function (selector) { return selector.release && typeof selector.release === 'function'; });`

Comment: it's related to the createSelector function I'm using.

Comment: I told you about that line in createSelector 5 comments ago!

Comment: You have asked about 2 different errors - the one in createSelector which is stated in the question title, and the typescript error in your test. I seriously suggest you concentrate on the first one first. Remove all type references in the test (at least temporarily) to fix the more serious problem.

Comment: Your selector works fine in the application, but not the test, because of the way you are building it in the test. You are somehow missing one or more of the first 3 parameters (which are selectors) used to create getCurrentServiceTree in the unit test.

Comment: @RichardMatsen You are right. Yes of course, I will review step by step debugging with breakpoints. I’m thinking this might be a circular dependency issue from what I was told today. It is very educational in any case. Thank you for your advice anyway. I would put the solution when I found it.

Answer (score 2):

I just faced the exact same error today.

It's very unclear at first where the error does come from.

What I've done to debug:

- Instead of running your test with `ng test` (and maybe headless), do not use the headless mode and also launch them with the argument `--no-sourcemaps`
- I had a (slightly) better message in the browser, at least telling me which file was causing the problem
- Even from there, it was not obvious where the problem was exactly, and I figured out that `ng test` does not report circular deps but `ng serve` does
- From there it was fairly easing finding the function causing the circular dependency and I just had to move it into another file (which made more sense anyway)